# Trying to make age guessing game in Javascript with counter function; has not worked hitherto

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, while-loop, logical-operators

Below is my code thus far for an educational exercise requiring that I make a guessing game with multiple hints and a counter function that terminates after four turns. I've searched SO extensively and found no help. I've reviewed my textbook to no avail. This code is as best as I can do with my present knowledge (class has only been on for a week, so admittedly that is paltry). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
if (answerSix != myAge) {
            while (guesses <= 4) {
                if (answerSix > myAge)
                    {alert('Too old!')};
                    guesses++;
                else if (answerSix < myAge)
                    {alert('Too young!')};
                    guesses++;
                }
                else if (guesses >= 4) {
                    {alert('You have guessed too many times! Game over!')};
                    {break};
                }
                }
            }
        else if (answerSix === myAge) {
                {alert('Got it like the \'79 SuperSonics!')};
                {break}
            }
            else {alert('Answer is invalid!')}
```

Comment: Since this is for a class I would suggest not looking for answers on SO but trying again yourself. You will learn a lot more by giving your teacher the wrong answer, than getting the right one from here.

Comment: hhhh. @CarlMarkham is right

Comment: Where are all you variables defined? Where are the values coming from and how is the function called? What errors do you get?

Comment: I would add though that you need to work on formatting your code and looking in to recursive functions that have set limits as oppose to while loops.

Comment: OP said it's the first week.. better leave recursive solutions for week 3 or 4 :)

Comment: @CarlMarkham That was my first instinct, but our instructor is insistent that, given our very limited faculties, we should seek help after fifteen minutes of concerted effort. In my own case, I worked on this problem for four hours before finding a solution, which I have explicated below!

Answer (score 0):

Give your teacher this answer, and let us know how he will assess you :)

```js
const MAX_GUESSES= 4;
class Game  extends React.Component{
  
  state = {started: false, end: false, guesses: 0}; 
  
  onStart(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.refs.myAge.value.length) 
      alert('Give a valid age before starting');
    else {
      this.setState({started: true, end: false, age: Number(this.refs.myAge.value) });
    }
  }

  onGuess(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     const guessed= Number(this.refs.answer.value);
     if (this.state.guesses >= MAX_GUESSES ) {
        this.setState({end: true, message: 'Failed! you reach max attempts'});
        return ;
     }  
     if (!guessed)
        alert('Please, put valid answer!')
     else {
       if(guessed < this.state.age) {
           alert('too young!');
           this.setState({guesses: this.state.guesses+1})
       }

       else if(guessed > this.state.age) {
         alert('too old!');
         this.setState({guesses: this.state.guesses+1})       
       }

       else {
         this.setState({
          end: true, message: `You win in ${this.state.guesses+1} attempt(s)`
         });
         return;
       }  
         
     }   
  }

  renderBeforeStart() {
    if (this.state.started || this.state.end) return null;
    return (
      <div>
         <input ref="myAge" type="number" placeholder="give your age before starting" /> years old <br />
         <button onClick={this.onStart.bind(this)}>Start Game </button>
      </div>
    ) 
  }
  
  renderAfterStart() {
    if (!this.state.started || this.state.end) return null;
    
    return(
       <div>
          <input ref="answer" type="number" placeholder="guess the age"/> <br />
          <button onClick={this.onGuess.bind(this)}> Guess ></button>
         
       </div>
    ) 
  }
  
  renderEnd() {
    if (!this.state.end) return ;
    
    return (<p>{this.state.message}</p>)
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          {this.renderBeforeStart()}
          {this.renderAfterStart()}
          {this.renderEnd()}
       </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.querySelector('section'))
```

```css
div div input {
  font-size:20px;
  padding-left:10px;
  padding-right:10px;
}

div div button {
 font-size : 22px;
 margin-top:10px; 
 margin-left:10px;
 cursor: progress;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<section />
```

Comment: Even being a complete novice, I was able to see that this answer required far too many lines. I appreciate a good joke as much as the next fellow, but I would appreciate sincere assistance! In any case, I was able to find a solution on our group work day.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all those who provided assistance! I was eventually able to find a solution that I wanted to share for posterity:

```
var myAge = 29;
        var counterSix = 0;
        while (counterSix < 4) {
            counterSix++;
            var answerSix = parseInt(prompt('What\s my age?'));
            if (counterSix === 4) {
                alert('Let\'s move on');
            } else if (answerSix === myAge) {
                alert('Got it like the \'79 SuperSonics!');
                break;
            } else if (answerSix < myAge) {
                alert ('Too young!')
            } else if (answerSix > myAge) {
                alert('Too old!'); questionCounter++
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is dumbed-down syntax and logic, but I wanted to make it understandable.

```
//correct age
var age = 6;
//number of times guessed
var counter = 0;
//maximum guesses
var maxCount = 4;

//function that takes a guess as a parameter
function guess(guess){
    /*if counter, (number of times guessed), 
    is equal to or greater than maxCount, (maximum guesses), 
    alert: 'You have guessed too many times! Game over!'*/
    if(counter >= maxCount){
        alert('You have guessed too many times! Game over!');
    /*else (the number of times guessed is less than maximum guesses))*/
    } else {
        /*if the type of the parameter 'guess' is not a number,
        alert: 'Answer is invalid!'*/
        if(typeof guess !== 'number'){
            alert('Answer is invalid!');
        /*else (the type of parameter 'guess' is a number)*/
        } else {
            /*if the guess parameter doesn't equal the correct age*/
            if(guess !== age){
                /*if the guess is less than the correct age,
                alert: 'Too young!'*/
                if(guess < age){
                    alert('Too young!');
                /*else, (the guess must be greater than the correct age),
                alert: 'Too old!'*/
                } else {
                    alert('Too old!');
                }
            /*else, (the guess parameter must equal the correct age),
            alert: 'Got it like the \'79 SuperSonics!'*/
            } else {
                alert('Got it like the \'79 SuperSonics!');
            }
        }
        /*increment the count of valid guesses by 1*/
        counter++;
    }
}

guess(4)
//Alerts: 'Too young!'
guess(8)
//Alerts: 'Too old!'
guess(6)
//Alerts: 'Got it like the \'79 SuperSonics!'
guess('hi')
//Alerts: 'Answer is invalid!'

//if guess count > 4
//Alerts: 'You have guessed too many times! Game over!'
```

Comment: Downvote because all you did was provide code, not describe how it works.

Comment: He already understands booleans, comparison operators, and if else statements. It would be an insult to OP's intelligence to explain what 'typeof' does. Some things are worthy of explanation, but others aren't, such as things taught in the first lesson of a programming class. (It's self explanatory)

Comment: I've never taken a programming class so excuse my ignorance on that matter. Regardless, you can't assume OP knows what you are writing. Better to comment each line of the code than to have the OP comment "What do you mean".

Comment: You're lucky. Unfortunately, I was "forced" to take a Java class in grade school. ;P PS: Updated with explanations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I ended up finding the solution myself before I returned to SO, and the solution bore a real resemblance to your solution. I appreciate your understanding of the scope of the question and my own knowledge, as well as your very helpful comments!

Comment: No problem, man. Glad you found the answer yourself. Keep it up!